# Get rows with same values and creates different columns in R

Tags: r, sequence

I have a df with repeated sequence in first column and I want to get the values within the same number (in column 1) and create columns with them.
Obs: my df has 25502100 rows and the sequence is formed by 845 values.
See one simple example of my df below:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), y = c(0.1,-2,-3,1,0,10,6,9))
```

I would like a function to transform this df in:

```
df_new
  x    y  z
1 1  0.1  0
2 2 -2.0 10
3 3 -3.0  6
4 4  1.0  9
```

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: Maybe: `t(unstack(df[2:1]))` ?

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(rn = c('y', 'z')[rowid(x)]) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = y)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   0.1     0
#2     2  -2      10
#3     3  -3       6
#4     4   1       9
```